# In a C# console app, how could I generate a Google Charts API request and save the result as an image?

Tags: c#, .net, google-visualization

Is it possible to make a call to the Google Charts API in a console app and save the result as a JPEG or PNG file? I can do it easily in a web app, just not quite sure how to do it in C#.

Many thanks-

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [googlechartsharp](http://code.google.com/p/googlechartsharp/) wrapper for the Charts API to get a URL at which you can view the chart.

Using the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes (or the `WebClient` class as per Joey's answer), you could capture the response stream as a byte array (the image) and write that to a file with the proper extension (a *.png file). Something like:

```
string chartUrl = chart.GetUrl();
byte[] chartBytes = null;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
chartBytes = client.DownloadData(chartUrl);

using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    memStream.Write(chartBytes, 0, chartBytes.Length);
}

File.WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\myChart.png", chartBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks- I'm trying it now. That looks awesome!

Comment: Awesome Cory- thanks! Perfect. (fileBytes should be changed to chartBytes when you have sec for those who come after us) :)

Comment: You can use `DownloadFile` to avoid the temporary `byte[]` (unless you need that, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class and its [DownloadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xz398a3f.aspx) or [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ez801hhe.aspx) methods. Constructing the URL to retrieve is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I added my Chart generator class (working perfectly). Just call it (as seen below) add your own event method to catch the chart once it is generated and save it to the HDD.

Calling the class and generating the chart:

```
   ChartGenerator charBartGen = new ChartGenerator();
            charBartGen.ChartCreated += new ChartCreatedEventHandler(charBartGen_ChartCreated);
            charBartGen.CreateBarChart(pictureBox2.Height, pictureBox2.Width,
                stats.MaxChecks,
                "Past 7 days",
                stats.Last7DayChecks1, stats.Last7DayChecks2);
```

The actual class:

```
   public class ChartGenerator
{
    public event ChartCreatedEventHandler ChartCreated;

    public string CreatePieChartUrl(int pHeight, int pWidth,
        string[] pSeries, string pTitle, int[] pData)
    {

        string st = String.Format(Misc.EnUk,
        @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs={0}x{1}&cht=p3&chd=t:", pWidth, pHeight);
        for (int i = 0; i < pData.Length; i++)
        {
            st += pData[i].ToString(Misc.EnUk) + ",";
        }

        st = st.TrimEnd(',');

        st += "&chdl=";
        for (int i = 0; i < pData.Length; i++)
        {
            st += pSeries[i].Replace(" ", "+") + "|";
        }
        st = st.TrimEnd('|');

        st += "&chtt=";
        st += pTitle.Replace(" ", "+") + "|";

        return st;
    }

    public void CreatePieChart(int pHeight, int pWidth,
        string[] pSeries, string pTitle, int[] pData)
    {
        string url = CreatePieChartUrl(pHeight, pWidth,
         pSeries, pTitle, pData);
        Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CreateChartAsync));
        th.Start(url);
    }

    public string CreateBarChartUrl(int pHeight, int pWidth, int pMax,
        string pTitle, int[] pData1, int[] pData2)
    {
      string st = String.Format(Misc.EnUk,
        @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,0,{0}&chxt=y&chbh=a&chs={1}x{2}&cht=bvs&chco=4D89F9,C6D9FD&chds=0,{0},0,{0}&chd=t:", 
            pMax, pWidth, pHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i < pData1.Length; i++)
        {
            st += pData1[i].ToString(Misc.EnUk) + ",";
        }
        st = st.TrimEnd(',');
        st += "|";

        for (int i = 0; i < pData2.Length; i++)
        {
            st += pData2[i].ToString(Misc.EnUk) + ",";
        }
        st = st.TrimEnd(',');

        st += "&chtt=";
        st += pTitle.Replace(" ", "+");

        return st;
    }

    public void CreateBarChart(int pHeight, int pWidth,int pMax,
      string pTitle, int[] pData1,int[] pData2)
    {
        string url = CreateBarChartUrl(pHeight, pWidth, pMax,
        pTitle, pData1, pData2);
        Thread th = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CreateChartAsync));
        th.Start(url);
    }

    private void CreateChartAsync(object pUrl)
    {
        string url = pUrl as string;

        try
        {
            if (url != null)
            {
                using (Stream stream = GetPageContentStream(url, false))
                {
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

                    if (img != null)
                    {
                        if (ChartCreated != null)
                        {
                            ChartCreated(this, new ChartCreatedEventArgs(img));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.Fail(err.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the stream of the given url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">The url</param>
    /// <param name="file">Whether this is a web file stream or a HttpWebRequest</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Stream GetPageContentStream(string url, bool file)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest wreq;
            WebResponse wres;

            if (file)
            {
                wreq = System.Net.FileWebRequest.Create(url);
            }
            else
            {
                wreq = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
                HttpWebRequest httpwrqst = wreq as HttpWebRequest;

                if (httpwrqst != null)
                {
                    httpwrqst.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    httpwrqst.Timeout = 10000;
                }
            }

            wres = wreq.GetResponse();
            return wres.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            Debug.Fail(err.Message);
            Logger.AppLogger.Instance.LogError("GetPageContentStream", err);
            return null;
        }
    }

}

public delegate void ChartCreatedEventHandler(object sender,ChartCreatedEventArgs e);

[Serializable]
public class ChartCreatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly Image mImage;

    public ChartCreatedEventArgs()
    {
    }

    public ChartCreatedEventArgs(Image pImage)
    {
        mImage = pImage;
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return mImage;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mudx- That's quite a solution! I'm not generating the Google Chart API calls, just processing them, so this one isn't for me, but thanks so much for helping! Cheers.